# Getting NPE in FirebaseDatabase.getReference()

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting NPE in production build on app start and only once after reinstalling with adb.

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.f.a(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzab.zza (SourceFile:276)
com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzab. (SourceFile:90)
com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzad.zzb (SourceFile:101)
com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzad.zza (SourceFile:42)
com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.zza (SourceFile:357)
com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(SourceFile:201)
```

I suppose I should not get NPE no matter what reference I am passing to getReference() method - although I am passing correct one.

This seems to happen with following firebase versions:

```
firebase_core_version = "16.0.3"
firebase_auth_version = "16.0.3"
firebase_database_version = "16.0.2"
```

I am unable to reproduce it using:

```
firebase_core_version = "16.0.0"
firebase_auth_version = "16.0.1"
firebase_database_version = "16.0.1"
```

Comment: This seems to be the same as this issue:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1447

Looks like an issue with database 16.0.2, will try and reproduce.

Comment: could you provide a full LogCat output?  Is there maybe another exception in the logs preceding this one?

Comment: Even better would be if you could show logs after setting `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);`

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Unfortunately I observed it only on production build and the output is from Crashlytics. No other crash was recorded. I will try to reproduce it tomorrow with debug version and let you know.

Comment: We discussed this issue further on GitHub, and at least for the affected user it boils down to a known regression that we are fixing in Firebase Database 16.0.3. Thanks for your patience while we roll this out!

Comment: I followed your conversation on GitHub. Thank you for the update!

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded firebase-ui-database from 4.2.0 to 4.1.0 and the problem went away

Answer (score 1):

add this to the ProGuard configuration, in order to exclude these classes from obfuscation:

```
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
```

the fact, that only the release build is being affected hints for this -

different library versions may provide different (library) consumer rules.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution that actually work's for me in [this link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1447#issuecomment-423162685)

The FirebaseMessagingService is causing me the issue. So, to reproduce, add:

**Manifest:**

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.class**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {

    try{
        DatabaseReference fRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        //  I am getting the reference to write the token in firebase database like:
        // fRef.child("token").setValue(token);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("MyFirebaseMsgService", e.getStackTrace().toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

}
}
```

In firebase-database 16.0.2, the line `DatabaseReference fRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();` is firing an exception:

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called
>   Looper.prepare()

whereas in 16.0.1 it wasn't.
When this exception is fired, the next `firebaseDatabase.getReference()` is crashing with the exception described initially.

**Dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.0'
//    implementation('com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.0') {
//        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-database'
//    }
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
}
```